# How to check if a process is in hang state (Linux)

Tags: linux

Is there any command in Linux through which i can know if the process is in hang state.

Comment: this is a superuser.com question.

Comment: @rsilva4 Or rather a unix one

Comment: `strace -p $process_id` - if there is not continuous output, that means it is waiting for something. If it waits too long, you could consider that "hung".

Comment: you could also use the timeout command to set a limit on a command. most people know if x amount of time goes by, it is too much. timeout has a return code of zero if the process exited normally.

Answer (score 31):

> Is there any command in Linux through which i can know if the process is in hang state.

There is no command, but once I had to do a very dumb hack to accomplish something similar. I wrote a Perl script which periodically (every 30 seconds in my case):

- run `ps` to find list of PIDs of the watched processes (along with exec time, etc)
- loop over the PIDs
- start `gdb` attaching to the process using its PID, dumping stack trace from it using `thread apply all where`, detaching from the process
- a process was declared hung if:

  - its stack trace didn't change and time didn't change after 3 checks
  - its stack trace didn't change and time was indicating 100% CPU load after 3 checks
- hung process was killed to give a chance for a monitoring application to restart the hung instance.

But that was very very very very crude hack, done to reach an about-to-be-missed deadline and it was removed a few days later, after a fix for the buggy application was finally installed.

Otherwise, as all other responders absolutely correctly commented, there is no way to find whether the process hung or not: simply because the hang might occur for way to many reasons, often bound to the application logic.

The only way is for application itself being capable of indicating whether it is alive or not. Simplest way might be for example a periodic log message "I'm alive".

Comment: While everyone is quick to cite the halting problem, I like how engineering-oriented your response is.  While it's true that we can't figure out whether arbitrary arithmetic process X **will** finish processing before it's finished processing, we can impose limits on the ones we know something about.  It's better to just fix the underlying problem, but killing and restarting a process isn't as dirty a hack as you make it out to be : )

Comment: Do you still happen to have this code somewhere?

Answer (score 27):

you could check the files

```
/proc/[pid]/task/[thread ids]/status
```

Comment: What should I look for in this file?

Comment: cat /proc/1241900/task/1241902/status | grep -i stat

Comment: `State: S (sleeping)`
and
`State: T (stopped)`

Comment: When I sent signal CTRL-Z to a process, then the state was T, i.e. stopped. In active state, it was S, i.e. sleeping.

Answer (score 9):

What do you mean by ‘hang state’? Typically, a process that is unresponsive and using 100% of a CPU is stuck in an endless loop. But [there's no way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) to determine whether that has happened or whether the process might not eventually reach a loop exit state and carry on.

Desktop hang detectors just work by sending a message to the application's event loop and seeing if there's any response. If there's not for a certain amount of time they decide the app has ‘hung’... but it's entirely possible it was just doing something complicated and will come back to life in a moment once it's done. Anyhow, that's not something you can use for any arbitrary process.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no hung state for a process. Now hung can be deadlock. This is block state. The threads in the process are blocked. The other things could be live lock where the process is running but doing the same thing again and again. This process is in running state. So as you can see there is no definite hung state. 
As suggested you can use the top command to see if the process is using 100% CPU or lot of memory.