# Identify if Process is Not Responding in Bash or Node.js

Tags: node.js, bash, macos, process, electron

Using an Electron App to control instances of other apps, but sometimes an instance will freeze. It shows up as `Not Responding` in Activity Monitor, but how can I tell that it's not responding from either Bash or Node.js so I can kill and restart the process? Thanks!

Comment: You're probably going to want to take a look at [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2)

Comment: @TinyGiant thanks, I think that's only for your own app, yea? I'm trying to tell if another application PID outside of mine is frozen.

Answer (score 0):

The following answer to a different question might help you:

> you could check the files
>
> ```
> /proc/[pid]/task/[thread ids]/status
> ```
>
> <sup>- [How to check if a process is in hang state (Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659065/how-to-check-if-a-process-is-in-hang-state-linux)</sup>

Comment: I'm on Mac, so I don't think that command works. I keep getting the `No such file or directory` error.

`ps PID` does return a `STAT` field with `R` but not sure if that would indicate if the process is frozen or not...

Comment: Can't help you with Mac, sorry... Still can be a valid answer for someone on Linux...